# True or False : What are some tricky questions in calculus? (or in overall)

Tags: calculus

I found some T/F questions that most people who have less experience may get wrong :

1. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f (1 + \frac{k}{n} )$ converges, is it equivalent to $\int_{1}^{2} f(x) dx$ for all function $f$?
2. For an integrable function $f$ and function $F$ such that $F ' = f$, is $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$ equivalent to $F(b) - F(a)$ for all $a, b \in dom(f)$?
3. Are all functions differentiable in their local extremum points?
4. If there are infinite points of discontinuity in function $f$, is $f$ not integrable all the time?
5. For all continuous functions in $\mathbb{R}$, are they always differentiable in their local extremum points?
6. For all differentiable functions in $\mathbb{R}$ and $a$ such that $f''(a) = 0$, is $(a, f(a))$ always an inflection point of $f$?
7. For all continuous functions in $\mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(a, f(a))$ is an inflection point of $f$, is $f$ differentiable in point $(a, f(a))$?
8. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-p}$ converges for $p \in \mathbb{R}$, does $p$ satisfy the following inequality : $p \geq 1$?
9. Does the following sum converge for prime numbers $p$ : $\sum_{p} \frac{1}{p}$?
10. Does the following identity hold : $\cot x = \frac{1}{\tan x}$?
11. Is the following statement true : $2 + 3i > 1 + 3i$ where $i = \sqrt{-1}$?
12. Are $-1, -\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}, \text{and} \:1$ the only possible rational values for $\sin (a \pi)$ where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$?
13. Does the quadratic formula work for quadratic equations with complex coefficients?
14. Does the discriminant work for quadratic equations with complex coefficients, as in quadratic equations with real coefficients? If not, what can we know from the discriminant?
15. Consider four given points $O, G, H, I$. If there exists a triangle where $O, G, H, I$ are the circumcenter, centroid, orthocenter, and the incenter of the triangle, is the triangle unique?
16. For triangle(s) for question 15, can they be constructed only using a ruler and a compass?

What are some trickiest T/F questions you can think of? I titled it as calculus, but you can bring some elementary stuff such as : "Let $f$ be a bijective function and $g$ be an inverse function of $f$. Do the intersection points of $f$ and $g$, if existing, lie on $y = x$ all the time?". (The answer is of course false.)

The answers are :
FFFF FFFT FFFT TFTF.

For question 14, we can only use the discriminant if $D = 0$.

Try providing some counterexamples for the false ones.

Comment: We ask that there be one question per post and that you show your work on the problem.

Comment: @RossMillikan I think the post is about wanting to create a database of these type of questions, not asking for the answers to them

Comment: It would be good to also provide the answers to these (maybe at the bottom), if this is going to be an educational post

Comment: What do you mean by the discriminant "working" in 14?

Comment: Why is 2 false? This is literally the fundamental theorem of calculus…

Comment: This shoudl be for math educator stack

Comment: Why is 10 false? Is the contention that $\cot x$ is not defined at $x = 0$, while $\tan x$ is defined and vanishes at $x = 0$? It's totally reasonable to write $\cot x = 1/\tan x$ with the understanding that the zeros of $\tan x$ are handled in the usual way, and $\cot x$ is meromorphic there.

Comment: @user7530 Nop. The function must be continuous...

Comment: @anomaly That's a tricky question...but $\;\cot\frac\pi2\;$ is well defined, whereas $\;\tan\frac\pi2\;$ is not and thus also not $\;\frac1{\tan\frac\pi2}\;$ . This kind of identities usually carry the condition "as long as both sides are well defined"

Comment: @anomaly For quadratic equations, we can determine whether the root of the equation is real of not - by the determinant D. If D>0, we have two different real roots. If D=0, we have two same real roots. If D<0, we have two different complex roots that are not real. The question is asking whether this can be applied to quadratic equations with complex coefficients as well.

Comment: Maybe trickier for #8 is to replace $p>1$ with $p \geq 1.$ It's still true, but students who confuse $P \implies Q$ with $Q \implies P$ might say false. In #4 it's unclear whether "with infinite points of discontinuity" refers to having at least one point where the function is locally unbounded or to having infinitely many points of discontinuity. Also, #12 should be worded more carefully (I think "false" can be argued as presently worded), since once $a$ is fixed, there is only one value now possible for $\sin(a\pi)$ (say something like "... must the value of $\sin(a\pi)$ be among ...").

Comment: Again with #4, "Are all functions not integrable with infinite points of discontinuity?" seems to be saying "Is it true that if a function is not integrable, then the function has infinite points of discontinuity." Maybe this is what you intended, but I originally thought you intended "Is it true that if a function has infinite points of discontinuity, then the function is not integrable.". My advice: If you're going to ask "tricky questions" to actual students (or include them on graded homework/tests), then you need to pay very careful attention to the wording of the questions.

Comment: What order relation are you using on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Edited.

Comment: @Evariste This is one counterexample : https://mblogthumb-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxNzA2MjBfMTk1/MDAxNDk3OTYzNjMyNjE5.BG9Kt2mEW3SNdgL_6pTM2Dw7nf4ILIm0RvJepuJdSLUg.dHZ793EzUYi35uCHHLNP4SRh4Gf7zzykGTisUk53OPkg.PNG.junhyuk7272/%EC%97%AD%ED%95%A8%EC%88%98%EC%99%80_y%3Dx%EC%9C%84%EC%9D%98_%EA%B5%90%EC%A0%90_%EC%98%88%EC%99%B8.png?type=w2

Comment: @Vue Yes of course, thank you, I made a trivial reasoning mistake!

Comment: @DonAntonio #2 is the (second FTC) which doesn't require continuity of $f=F'$ (a proof, using mean-value theorem, can be found in Spivak's Calculus Chapter 14 Theorem 2)

Comment: @user580918 Point taken: I was thinking of the corollary to Theorem 1. Yet $\;(2)\;$ still is false, I guess, because it could be that  $\;f\;$ is *not* integrable precisely on $\;[a,b]\;$...although I'd say that stating that $\;f\;$ is integrable would mean that it is so in ALL its domain... and I presume all the "integrable" in these questions mean in fact Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Milten given the types of questions asked here and the tag (calculus), I think it's fairly safe to assume we're only speaking of Riemann-integrability (hence I referenced Spivak :). Even for Lebesgue integrals, one has the following theorem (Proven in Rudin's RCA): "if $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is differentiable at every point of $[a,b]$ and $f'\in L^1([a,b])$, then $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^bf'(t)\,dt$". In your link, the Cantor function is only a.e differentiable (and this post explicitly mentions integrability and doesn't even reference the 'a.e' concept), so I think it's very safe to say #2 is true.

Comment: @DonAntonio, user580918 Haha, whoops!! I completely missed that $f$ is assumed integrable in #2. I agree, it's true then (under any reasonable interpretation)! Deleting my other comment 